# Datetime axis spacing

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, axis

I have an errorbar plot where the xaxis is a list of datetime objects. The standard plotting method will put the first and last point so that they are right on the bounding box of the plot. I would like to offset by a half tick so that the first and last point can be seen clearly.

```
ax.axis(xmin=-0.5,xmax=len(dates)-0.5)
```

does not work for obvious reasons. It would be nice to be able to do this without hardcoding any dates.

The following will produce a plot which has ten points but you can really only see 8.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = [datetime.date(2002, 3, 11) - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 10)]
yvalues = [2, 4, 1,7,9,2, 4, 1,7,9]
errorvalues = [0.4, 0.1, 0.3,0.4, 0.1,.4, 0.1, 0.3,0.4, 0.1]

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.errorbar(dates,yvalues,yerr=errorvalues,fmt='.') 
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Comment: It'd be much easier to help you out with some example data. For instance, certain approaches might fall in or out of favor based on how far spread apart your dates are.

Comment: I was hoping for a generic way. The actual dates don't matter. Lets assume we want equal spacing between dates regardless of the values in the list. The goal would be to have the ticks start half a space late and end half a space early. I gave my current hack in an answer below.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It's good practice to provide a simple, copy/pastable script as a launching off point. The easier it is to help you, the more help you'll get. As it stands now I have to activate a conda environment, start an ipython notebook server, and create my own fake data and hope it's representative of the problems your facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set spacing with margins()

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = [datetime.date(2002, 3, 11) - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 10)]
yvalues = [2, 4, 1,7,9,2, 4, 1,7,9]
errorvalues = [0.4, 0.1, 0.3,0.4, 0.1,.4, 0.1, 0.3,0.4, 0.1]

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.errorbar(dates,yvalues,yerr=errorvalues,fmt='.') 
ax.margins(x=0.05)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

An ugly fix for this could be the following

```
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.errorbar(range(len(dates)),yvalues,yerr=errorvalues) 
ax.set_xticks(range(len(dates))
ax.set_xticklabels(dates, fontsize=8)
ax.axis(xmin=-0.5,xmax=len(dates)-0.5)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

The downside to this is that the axis objects are not of the datetime type so you can't use many functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ax.margins` to get what you want.

Without seeing your data, it's hard to know how big of a margin you actually want. If you're plotting with python datetime-types, a margin of 1 corresponds to a pretty big margin:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y)
[t.set_ha('right') for t in ax.get_xticklabels()]
[t.set_rotation_mode('anchor') for t in ax.get_xticklabels()]
[t.set_rotation(45) for t in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.margins(x=1)
```

But again, it's hard to get too specific without seeing your existing data and plots.

Comment: @Keith does ax.margins not work with error bar plots (which are essentially bar plots)?